# Does FlexBuilder 3 work with Eclipse 3.5.1?

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse, macos, eclipse-plugin, flexbuilder

I m trying to install Flex Builder 3 into Eclipse 3.5.1 as a plugin on Mac 10.6.2.

During the installation phase, FB3 says it only support eclipse 3.3 & 3.4. But I started the installation anyway.

After the installation was done, I can't find Flex perspective from Eclipse. So I google around and found out the possible way to manually add this link file from folder "links" to point to the FB3 Plugin folder. I did that and FB perspective can be shown now. But when I try to switch to FB perspective, error occurs:

Problems opening perspective:
'com.adobe.flexbuilder.editors.mxml.ui.perspectives.development'

Anyone has done this successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately Eclipse 3.5 is unsupported by Flex Builder 3. There are a few bugs for this:
http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB-21025
http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB-21284

Please comment on those bugs and vote for them.

I've created [a work-around](http://www.jamesward.com/2009/09/29/flex-builder-3-on-eclipse-3-5/) for one of the major issues related to displaying problems.